# change product name in view cart page

Tags: checkout, cart

i want to append some extra thing to all product name in view cart how can i do it via observer

please tell which observer should i use or call for that

Answer (score 1):

mour,you can do this by event `sales_quote_item_set_product`

### Config.xml code:

```
 <events>
      <sales_quote_item_set_product> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <sales_quote_item_set_product_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento58323/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>setmynameOption</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </sales_quote_item_set_product_handler>
        </observers>
      </sales_quote_item_set_product>
    </events>
```

And

### Observer.php

function change name

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_58323_Model_Observer
{

    public function setmynameOption(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $Event = $observer->getEvent();
        
        //Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_item_set_product', array('product' => $product,'quote_item' => $this));
        $product=$Event->getProduct();
        $quote_item=$Event->getQuoteItem();
        $quote_item->setName($product->getName().'myappend');
    return 
    }
}
```

Comment: not works, i want to append it on view cart page "checkout/cart/" for all product name

Answer (score 1):

Magento product name at Cart has been coming from  function `getProductName`()  at class 
`Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Configurable`

and

`Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer`

You need to change on this function.So rewrite those two blocks and do `change` on function `getProductName`.

```
public function getProductName()
{
    if ($this->hasProductName()) {
        return $this->getData('product_name');
    }
    return $this->getProduct()->getName(). 'myAppend';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing..... after trying all the day finally I ended up doing adding an extra column at the table "sales_flat_quote_item" named custom_product_name and saved the modified name.

just like $item->setCustomProductName($modified_name) and save it
$item->save();

inside the deault.phtml (your_theme/checkout/cart/item/default)
invoke the modified name $item->getCustomProductName()..

of course, careful with the other product names...
so check the product type using if statement