# Change name of dynamically created product in observer

Tags: event-observer, magento-1, quote

**EDIT: SOLVED**

I had to override this method from Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer to use `$this->getItem()->getName()` instead of `$this->getProduct()->getName()`.

```
public function getProductName()
{
    if ($this->hasProductName()) {
        return $this->getData('product_name');
    }
    return $this->getProduct()->getName();
}
```

How can I change name of the product that I am creating here in Observer.php `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event so that I see it in cart view.

I tried setName() and setData to change the name, but it didn't work.

I want to change name of $exampleItem, changing price works, but changing name doesn't.

```
class Test_Example_Model_Observer
{
    public function cartProductAddAfter($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem(); // get product that gets added to cart
        $exampleQty = $product->getQtyToAdd(); // get quantity of added product

        $exampleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'EXAMPLE'); // get the example product
        $exampleToAdd = $exampleProduct->load($exampleProduct->getId()); // load the example product

        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(); // get quote
        $exampleItem = $quote->addProduct($exampleToAdd, $exampleQty); // add example product to quote matching quantity of the normal product
        $exampleItem->setCustomPrice(444);
        $exampleItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(444);
        $quote->save(); // save quote
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please follow the below links http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104366/how-to-change-product-name-in-quote-item-dynamically http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58323/change-product-name-in-view-cart-page

Comment: @NAGARAJUK I already tried it. If I did a `var_dump()` on that item then it showed that name was changed, but in cart view nothing was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to override this method from Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer to use `$this->getItem()->getName()` instead of `$this->getProduct()->getName()`.

```
public function getProductName()
{
    if ($this->hasProductName()) {
        return $this->getData('product_name');
    }
    return $this->getProduct()->getName();
}
```